# Google App Engine - Retrieving Parameters from URI in a doGet()?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, get

In the doGet() method of a servlet, how can I get parameters given within the URI? For example, if I have a servlet mapped to `/getContentServlet`, Then one could do a jQuery `$.get()` to the URI `http://mysite.appspot.com/getContentServlet?var1=foo&var2=bar`:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    // Get parameters "foo" and "bar" from the URI
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the [getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    String var1 = request.getParameter("var1"); // foo
    String var2 = request.getParameter("var2"); // bar
}
```